# Incorrect apple-touch-icon is being loading

Tags: ios, safari, apple-touch-icon

This code, put in the `head` element, loads the 120px icon on my iPhone 6 Plus when I go to add the site to the home screen, even though the [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/iad/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconMatrix.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH27) says that shouldn't be the case.

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="120x120" href="img/icon-120.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="img/icon-180.png">
```

Thoughts?

Comment: What happens if you reverse the order?

Comment: It makes no difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is either a bug of iOS or a bug in Apple specs, but in any case this is not normal.

This issue was discussed as an [issue of the html5-boilerplate project](https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/pull/1599) and also documented in [RealFaviconGenerator compatibility page](http://realfavicongenerator.net/favicon_compatibility) (full disclosure: I'm the author of this site). The bottom line:

- Despite of the specs, the iPhone 6 / iOS 8 does not use the 180x180 icon for the home screen, but the 120x120 icon. This is what you observe.
- The 180x180 icon is used in two situations: when a bookmark is created on an iPhone 6 / iOS 8 (so the iPhone 6 does use this icon after all) and for add to home screen on an iPad 3rd generation / iOS 8 (so some iOS devices do use this icon for home screen).